# Replace ip:port to another ip:port using sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, docker, sed

I have nginx config file, where i have ip adress of my container. If i recreate container it will have the new ip, so i want to replace it.

I have .sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip_new=$(sudo docker exec -ti pqf_ui_dev hostname -I) #to assign  container ip to this variable
sudo sed  "s~proxy_pass http[:]//[^ ][:]80*~proxy_pass http://$ip_new:80~"  -i /etc/nginx/sites- 
enabled/docker-pqf
```

so for example if my old ip:port was 172.17.0.1:80 and the new one is 172.17.0.2:80, my sed replace it like:

```
proxy_pass http://172.17.0.4 ^M:80
```

How i can change my script to replace ip without this `^M`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

`ip_new=$(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' pqf_ui_dev)`

Instead of:

`ip_new=$(sudo docker exec -ti pqf_ui_dev hostname -I)`

And maybe you may like this sed:

`sudo sed -E 's~(proxy_pass https?://)[^ :;]+(:?\d*)~\1'$ip_new'\2~' -i /etc/nginx/sites- 
enabled/docker-pqf`

*It is not perfect, but way more universal and without repeating searchtext like proto, host, port.*

Comment: Great! Happy coding :D

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this I would run the nginx proxy in a container also and proxy_pass to the container name rather than a dynamic IP that will keep changing.

e.g. if using a compose file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx
    # Docker config required for nginx
  backend: 
    # Config for your backend service
    ports:
     - "80:80"
```

Then in your nginx conf file you can refer to the backend service as http://backend:80 and docker DNS will resolve the IP address for you complete with load balancing if you have multiple instances running.

Comment: Nginx proxy is really a good idea, and I tried to make by this way. But unfortunately, we can't assign the SSL certificates to make https connection. While we understand what is wrong, we need a temporary solution. But, thank you for your answer!

Comment: I'm confused now, if nginx isn't running in docker then why do you need the internal dynamic IP address? This won't be visible outside of the docker network. If you map the port of your service to a port on the host then you can use the host's IP to call your service.

Comment: Our problem was solved, we have nginx which is running in host ubuntu machine, to which was assigned domain name. In sites-enabled directory we create additional config file for our container,  to which assign sub domain name, and redirect all requests from this domain to our container